# Azure websites throw 500 error when there is a colon in the URL

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

External clients are hitting my Azure website with urls that contain the colon (:) character.  The request are not valid, but on my old IIS server it would give a 404 error.  On Azure, the same URL will give a 500 error.  This wastes my time, as I have to check the logs.  This is an example of a request:

http://www.example.com/http:/www.example.com

Is there any way of avoiding this behaviour on the server side, and give 4xx error instead?  Keep in mind, this problem is on Azure only, and I do not control the requests.

Comment: To be more precise, it looks like it's the :/ sequence that triggers this rather than just colon. Still, it seems incorrect.

Comment: You are right, it is.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am dealing with same issue in azure. Googlebot is hitting our site with these malformed URLs, triggering alerts.

Comment: Yes, sort of.  I set up a separate "proxy" website that now receives all inbound traffic.  This site is empty, except for a web.config file.  The web.config redirects all traffic to my original site (now with a different dns entry) using url-rewrite.  The 500 failures now happen on the "proxy" site, and only valid requests are forwarded to the original site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a .NET application, then this is caused by ASP.NET HTTP runtime, more specifically by its request filtering feature.

If the URL path contains any of the disallowed characters (`<,>,*,%,&,:,\\,?`), the runtime throws the exception and because of the exception the IIS returns error code 500.

> System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

You can [configure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) disallowed characters in your `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="*,%" />
</system.web>
```

But i would be careful, because there might be some security implications of such change.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to help on an Azure web site.  I have changed the targetFramework attribute to 4.6, as this is the version used there.

Comment: The error happens before Azure looks at the web.config.

Comment: Do you know how to disable this 'Request filtering feature' ? I'm running PHP on Windows ( Azure App Service ) and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the KUDU Console in Azure add the file applicationhost.xdt to D:\home\site.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-   Transform">
 <system.applicationHost>
<sites>
  <site name="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
           <virtualDirectoryDefaults xdt:Transform="Insert" allowSubDirConfig="false" />
           </site>
</sites>
```

This does the job, but has an unfortunate side effect, in that any web.config in any application subdirectory was ignored. For our side, this had the effect of not loading any static files which meant the site did not work properly.

This will work fine for any site having a single web.config at root level.

Comment: This code doesn't work on IIS 10. Requests are still there.