# http or https in request path to a node server creates an error

Tags: node.js, azure, url-rewriting, cors-anywhere

I am trying to make [corsanywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) work on Azure, and actually it works if I request something like this:

```
https://myserver.azurewebsites.net/www.remoteserver.com/query=john
```

But if I call this, I get a 500 error and I don't know how to track it (no error is produced in the logs in this case):

```
https://myserver.azurewebsites.net/http://www.remoteserver.com/query=john
```

This kind of request works well on the corsanywhere demo site or when I run my node app on my dev machine.

**Update**:
Node on Azure needs a web.config file. Here is mine:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="DynamicContent">
             <match url="/*" />
             <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am wondering if this could be the culprit...

Thanks for your help

Comment: how are you running your node app? i mean node index.js, pm2 start index.js, nodemon index.js, etc.

Comment: node server.js is mentioned inside package.json

Comment: you should be seeing your errors right there in the console, where you wrote `node server.js`

Comment: hummm, this runs on Azure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure App Service (Windows OS), the characters `:/` are not allowed in the URL path. This was discussed on SO before: [Azure websites throw 500 error when there is a colon in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197132/azure-websites-throw-500-error-when-there-is-a-colon-in-the-url).

You could try a solution in @TimBunting's answer, or host your application on a [Linux App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs) instead.