# Azure 'A potentially dangerous Request.Path' log with colon (:)

Tags: windows, azure, iis, host

I'm going crazy searching for this event but I didn't find a single solution for that.

That's the situation :
Wordpress in a Azure **Windows** App Service.

All works fine, but in the eventLog.xml a see every day, seems scheduled, a log like that :

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

The page request is like that :

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/my-category/my-article/https:/www.mywebsite.com/my-page/
```

I'm **sure** that those links are **not** in the google serp and there is **no link to those pages**.

---

I found that :
[Azure websites throw 500 error when there is a colon in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197132/azure-websites-throw-500-error-when-there-is-a-colon-in-the-url)
It's the same error, but I can't afford the same solution.

It seems to be related to the IIS Request Filtering feature, but I'm not a Windows wizard and I don't know how to disable this feature on **Azure**.

Can anyone solve this issue?

---

**IIS VERSION** : 10

Comment: The `:` character is not allowed in the path of the URL, you can try to use an arbitrary character as escape character or remove the `:`.

Comment: I know that's is not allowed, but I'm not doing those requests... I want to know why I see those logs. I've noticed also that the same site hosted on linux __doesn't__ request those urls.

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view your request process, and then find out where the problem occurred, finally you can try to use url rewrite to remove or disable `:` .